# Collisions with hashing (CLRS)

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, clrs

I am trying to solve this problem (CLRS, 3rd edition, exercise 11.2-1):

> Suppose we use a hash function h to hash n distinct keys into an array of length m. Assuming simple uniform hashing, what is the expected number of collisions?

The correct solution is n(n-1)/2m. This is taken from instructor's manual of CLRS.

My solution is as follows:

- For insert of key 1: expected # of collisions with predecessors = 0
- For insert of key 2: expected # of collisions with predecessors = 1/m
- For insert of key 3: expected # of collisions with predecessors = 1/m*(1/m) + (m-1)/m*(2/m) = (2m-1)/m^2

My reasoning: there is a 1/m chance of key 1 & 2 colliding in 1 slot, which means the probability of collision for key 3 is 1/m. There is a (m-1)/m chance that key 1 and key 2 were not colliding, which means they are in different slots and the probability of collision for key 3 is 2/m.

The expected number of collisions for 3 keys, by linearity of expectation = 0 + 1/m + (2m-1)/m^2 = (3m-1)/m^2

According to CLRS, the expected number of collisions for 3 keys should be 3/m.

***I know how to find the correct solution using indicator RV's***.

My question is: **Where did I make a mistake in my solution?** Why is it different?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the instructor manual seems off. Simple example, 12 keys [0..11], hashed into a 3 element array via h(k) = k mod 3.

We have bucket 0 with keys 0,3,6,9. Bucket 1 has keys 1,4,7,10. Bucket 2 has keys 2,5,8,11. Collisions for bucket 0 are {(0,3), (0,6), (0, 9), (3,6), (3,9), (6,9)}, cardinality = 6. By symmetry, buckets 1 and 2 also contribute with 6 collisions each.

Hence, total number of collisions for this example is 18. If the expected number of collisions is given by the n(n-1)/2m formula, that'd be 12*11/6 = 22.

Wrong.

I reached another formula, by reasoning thusly:

1. If we assume uniform hashing, the number of keys in each bucket should be expected to be the same as in any other, that is n/m. So, total number of collisions would be m*Collisions(single bucket).
2. Now, how do we get the number of collisions in each bucket? Well, each of the keys that is in it collisions with all the others, and the set of collisions is defined by taking pairs of them at a time. Hence, we're looking at the number combinations of (n/m) elements taken two at a time

C(n/m, 2) = (n/m)!/[2!(n/m -2)!] = [(n/m)(n/m -1)(n/m -2)!]/[2*(n/m -2)!].

(n/m - 2)! terms in the numerator/denominator cancel each other, and we get

C(n/m, 2) = [(n/m)(n/m - 1]/2 = n(n-m)/2m^2

So, total number of collisions is m*C(n/m, 2) = n(n-m)/2m.

Let's apply this to our example, shall we?

12(12-3)/2*3 = 12*9/6 = 18

Which is exactly the cardinality of the set of collisions in our example.

Answer (score -1):

> there is a 1/m chance of key 1 & 2 colliding in 1 slot, which means the probability of collision for key 3 is 1/m

It depends on how collisions are handled.  For closed hashing implementations, an alternative bucket will be selected for key 2, so the chance of a collision at the first hashed-to bucket when inserting key 3 is still 2/m (then there may be a further chance at the second-choice bucket, 3rd choice bucket etc. - see below).  For open hashing, the colliding elements will be chained off the same bucket, so if keys 1 and 2 collide there's a reduced 1/m chance of key 3 first hashing to the same bucket (and there may be a further chance of colliding on the second-choice bucket etc.).

So, a big problem is you're assuming different collision-handling approaches: closed vs. open hashing.

That said, the question as you've presented it is vague - how values are added after a collision can affect the probabilities of further collisions.  For example, rehashing using an alternative hash algo that also achieves simple uniform hashing implies another #inserted/#buckets collision probability on each post-collision re-insertion attempt, so the series goes:

- key 1: expected # collisions = 0
- key 2: expected # collisions = 1/m + 1/m*1/m + 1/m*1/m*1/m + ...
- key 3: expected # collisions = 2/m + 2/m*2/m + 2/m*2/m*2/m + ...

It'll be a different for e.g. linear probing, quadratic probing etc..